# Conflict between Mootools and jQuery

Tags: jquery, mootools

I have got a script that is executed after Login- in a doLogin.php file. After success the php code is exit('OK'); when it was mootools only all worked perfectly. Now when Im trying to go jquery I get on /dologin.php only a blank page with OK message. Could you help me how to solve this? I tried to change some functions but doesn't work.

**Jquery Attempt**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery.fn.addEvent = jQuery.fn.bind; //updated
    $('login').bind('submit', function(e) {
        // Prevents the default submit event from loading a new page.
        e.stop();

        // Show the spinning indicator when pressing the submit button...
        $('ajax_loading').css('display','block');

        // Hide the submit button while processing...
        $('submit').css('display','none');
        $('register').css('display','none');

        // Set the options of the form's Request handler.
        // ("this" refers to the $('login') element).
        this.set('send', { onComplete: function(response) {
            $('ajax_loading').css('display','none');

            if(response == 'OK'){
              $('status').set('html', '<div class="col-md-6"> '+
                                      '<div class="panel panel-primary">'+
               ' <div class="panel-heading">'+
                   ' <h3 class="panel-title">'+
                   '     <span class="fa  fa-cog"></span> Quick Redirect</h3>'+
                '</div>'+
               ' <div class="panel-body">'+
              '      You are now logged it! <br />'+
             ' <div class="progress progress-striped active">' +
               ' <div style="width: 100%" class="progress-bar"></div>' +
             ' </div>'+
              '      </div>'+
           ' </div>'+
        '</div>' );


            setTimeout('go_to_private_page()', 3000);
            }
            else
            {
               $('login_response').set('html', response);
              // Show the login button
              $('submit').setStyle('display','');
              $('register').setStyle('display','');
            }
        }});

        // Send the form.
        this.submit();
    });
});

function go_to_private_page()
{
window.location = 'admin/index.php'; // Members Area
}
```

**Original file**

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {

    $('login').addEvent('submit', function(e) {
        // Prevents the default submit event from loading a new page.
        e.stop();

        // Show the spinning indicator when pressing the submit button...
        $('ajax_loading').setStyle('display','block');

        // Hide the submit button while processing...
        $('submit').setStyle('display','none');
        $('register').setStyle('display','none');

        // Set the options of the form's Request handler.
        // ("this" refers to the $('login') element).
        this.set('send', { onComplete: function(response) {
            $('ajax_loading').setStyle('display','none');

            if(response == 'OK')
            {
              $('status').set('html', '<div class="col-md-6"> '+
                                      '<div class="panel panel-primary">'+
               ' <div class="panel-heading">'+
                   ' <h3 class="panel-title">'+
                   '     <span class="fa  fa-cog"></span> Quick Redirect</h3>'+
                '</div>'+
               ' <div class="panel-body">'+
              '      You are now logged it! <br />'+
             ' <div class="progress progress-striped active">' +
               ' <div style="width: 100%" class="progress-bar"></div>' +
             ' </div>'+
              '      </div>'+
           ' </div>'+
        '</div>' );


            setTimeout('go_to_private_page()', 3000);
            }
            else
            {
               $('login_response').set('html', response);
              // Show the login button
              $('submit').setStyle('display','');
              $('register').setStyle('display','');
            }
        }});

        // Send the form.
        this.send();
    });
});

function go_to_private_page()
{
window.location = 'admin/index.php'; // Members Area
}
```

Comment: You wrote "when it was mootools only all worked perfectly"... keep with MooTools.

Comment: It happened when I added jQuery JavaScript Library v1.3.2 .js and I need both of them so I can't stay by it.

Comment: You can use both at the same time if you need. Btw, jQuery 1.3 is very old. I'm not sure if it works with new browsers. Anyway, if you post your code here and the error you got when you had both, maybe its possible to fix so both can be used. You can start by replacing all your MooTools `$` by `document.id`.

Comment: the other code is a very simple function with ajax to refresh a query for "currently online users" its few lines. Its all about the pasted code / the 1.3.2 jq js lib

Comment: Where is your jQuery code that should work with this Mootools code?

Comment: Check the first post. There is my jquery attempt + original mootools under it

Comment: I mean you can use jQuery __and__ Mootools. Put back that code in just Mootools which (using your words) _"all worked perfectly"_. So if you have jQuery somewhere else paste it here. Otherwise use only Mootools and remove the jQuery library file... Remember the `$` in Mootools is the same as `document.id`, so using that instead might be good if you have jQuery in the same page.